# Formula to find the last " \ " in a filepath and remove all after that

Tags: excel, ms-office

So I have an excel task that involves taking filepaths (C:\foo...) and getting just the path (that is, removing the actual file name from the path).  I can't seem to get the SEARCH/FIND function to work since it is always finding the first "\" in the file path (after the drive designation) and only removes 3 or so characters.

Is there a formula that will allow me to trim after the last "\" in the filepath?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, your question would be better off on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

You can use `LEFT`, with `FIND` and `SUBSTITUTE`... and a couple others:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND(CHAR(1), SUBSTITUTE(A1, "\", CHAR(1), LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "\", ""))))-1)
```

`LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "\", "")` basically gives the number of `\` in the string.

`SUBSTITUTE(A1, "\", CHAR(1), LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "\", ""))` This part substitute the last `\` by a character called `CHAR(1)`.

Then, use `FIND` to get the position of this character and minus 1 to remove that found character's position, to be `LEFT` (both figuratively and literally) with the part you need.

If you need the last backslash, remove the `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this version

`=LEFT(A1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND("\",A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))))`

The `FIND` function returns an array of numbers including the positions of all the "\" characters in A1 - `LOOKUP` takes the last number from that array - i.e. the position of the last "\" and then `LEFT` just takes the relevant portion based on that number

Answer (score 2):

Alternates:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)),"")
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99))))
```

And to remove the ending \ if desired:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\"&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)),"")
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)))-1)
```