# Remove text after last Backslah

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a bunch of file paths that look like this:

> e:\Datasheet\Docs\images\1.2.840\1.2.840.113986

I'm looking for a way in Excel to trim off everything after the last backslash `\`.

I've tried **`=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)`** but all I get back is two numbers.

The expected outcome I'm looking for is: e:\Datasheet\Docs\images\1.2.840\

Comment: Will the number before you truncate it always end in a decimal?

Comment: no, actually it'll end in a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to go four folders "deep" this will work (place in B1):

`=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",";",5),SEARCH(";",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",";",5))-1)`

edit: Try this one too, it should work for everything else (no matter how many folders):

`=LEFT(A1, FIND(CHAR(1), SUBSTITUTE(A1, "\", CHAR(1), LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "\", ""))))-1)`

(Thanks to [@Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18390137/4650297)) for that one.

Comment: that worked perfectly. I used 8 instead of 5 to get to the backslash I was expecting. Thank you!

Comment: I updated with a more dynamic formula, which also works.  If this is what you're looking for, would you kindly flag as the answer? (click the check mark on the left, thanks!)

Comment: yea I noticed that I have folder paths that the 8 or 5 would't work for. so the dynamic method you posted was much better and did the job.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
=LEFT(A1,MAX((MID(A1,ROW(1:999),1)="\")*ROW(1:999)))
```

Confirm it with Control-Shift-Enter.

And here is a short formula that does not need to be array-entered:

```
=LEFT(A1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND("\",A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,LEN(A1))))))
```