# Populate cell with substring following last / in the string

Tags: excel, csv, substring, vba

I have a CSV in which column A is populated with strings, such as:

ABCDE/FGHI/JKL/MNOPQR

I need to populate column C with everything after the last occurrence of the "/". In this example, it would have to be "MNOPQR".

Is there a function that could be used for this? "RIGHT" doesn't seem to do the trick. I don't know what the length of the substring will be in each row, so I definitely have to look for the "/".

Comment: Loop backwards by characters from the right until you hit the first `/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: last character/string match in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string)

Comment: Check out that other question; it's pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your text is in A4, put this in another cell:

```
=MID(A4,LEN(LEFT(A4,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A4,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"/",""))))))+1,LEN(A4)-LEN(LEFT(A4,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A4,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"/",""))))))+1)
```

I think that should work. Thanks to [@Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18390137/4650297) for the main part, where it finds the last `/` in a string.

[image]

edit:
Per @ScottCraner, this is shorter: `=MID(A1,SEARCH("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))‌​))+1,LEN(A1))`

Comment: This one is a little shorter: `=MID(A1,SEARCH("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))+1,LEN(A1))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Nice! I knew there would probably be a quicker way, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Which by the way is nearly exact to the formula in the link by Grad eh bacon

Comment: Why is it searching for `"}}}"`?

Comment: See the link for a better explanation, but in essence I am replacing the last "/" with "}}}" then searching for it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I'm able to get the original solution you proposed to work. The shorter version is giving me a function error, I'll have to look into it some more.

Comment: @katharey - if this works for you, do you mind marking as the answer (click the check outline left of my post)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit shorter formula to return the last delimited substring in a string.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

Replace the delimiter with 99 spaces, then return the rightmost 99 characters.  The leading characters must be spaces also, so TRIM gets rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

A simple formula approach using `FilterXML` might be:

```
    =FILTERXML("<items><i>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</i><i>") & "</i></items>","//i[position()=last()]")
```

Profitting from the dynamic features of vers. 2019+ you can change the cell address to a range input, e.g. A1:A10 allowing output in a so called spill range.

**VBA approach**

As the `VBA` tag has been recently added to OP,
an obvious VBA approach would be to split the string input and get the last array element via `Ubound()`:

```
    Dim tmp As Variant
    tmp = Split("ABCDE/FGHI/JKL/MNOPQR", "/")
    Debug.print tmp(Ubound(tmp))     ' ~~> MNOPQR
```